# Why doesn't VS2015 debugger show the function address correctly in the watch window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

C++ code in Visual Studio 2015 debugger. Platform: Window 10

The watch window says:

**Name**:*functionPointer*   **Value**:0x012812d0  **Type**:void(*)(float)

**Name**:*printStuff*        **Value**:0x01282440   **Type**:void(float)

**Name**:*&printStuff* **Value**:0x01282440  **Type**:void(*)(float)

However, the output windows says:

functionPointer = 012812D0 printStuff = 0x012812D0 &printStuff = 0x012812D0 
This is the print stuff function

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
void printStuff(float)
{
    cout << "This is the print stuff function." << endl;
}

const float PI = 3.1415926f;

int main()
{
    void(*functionPointer)(float); // *functionPointer is a pointer
    functionPointer = printStuff;  // *functionPointer point to function printstuff
    cout << "functionPointer = " << functionPointer << "  " << "printStuff = " << printStuff << "  " << "&printStuff = " << &printStuff << endl;
    functionPointer(PI);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Please show text instead of images (Visual Studio allows you to copy text from watch window)

Comment: @P.Zhang please don't put lengthy information into comments but [edit] your question.

Comment: The watch window says:

Name:   functionPointer 
Value:  0x012812d0 {jan29.exe!printStuff(float)}    
Type:   void(*)(float)

Name:   printStuff
Value:  0x01282440 {jan29.exe!printStuff(float)}
Type:   void(float)

Name:   &printStuff
Value:  0x01282440 {jan29.exe!printStuff(float)}    
Type:   void(*)(float)   


However, the output windows says:
“functionPointer = 012812D0 printStuff = 0x012812D0 &printStuff = 0x012812D0 
This is the print stuff function”

Comment: OK, I reedit it. @MichaelWalz

Comment: This probably has something to do with function pointer actually pointing at dispatch table at debug mode. Emitted code uses this dispatch table entry as function address while debug watch shows real function address.

Comment: @VTT I don't think so, the disassembly in debug mode shows nothing special. It looks like a bug in Visual Studio to me. BTW Visual Studio 2017exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Have you tried following function invocation through pointer? It should lead you into dispatch table and then jump into real function.

Comment: @VTT I thinks something is missing in your previous comment, but I checked the invocation through the function pointer `functionPointer` and nothing special either, just a `call  dword ptr [functionPointer]` .

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, but stepping into it will lead you not into `printStuff`, but into dispatch table entry with a single `jmp` instruction that will lead into `printStuff`.

Comment: @VTT you are right. Make that an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @VTT I got that far and verified what in Release this doesn't happen. So it seems fine that we get this behavior. However, why does it use a dispatch table in debug - Edit&Continue (the logical suspect) didn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be because of incremental linking. When it is enabled, the function is assembled in one memory address and another address contains a jump table entry with one jump instruction to the 'real' address. The function is always called by calling the jump table. If you disable incremental linking, the 'detour' via the jump table goes away and also your example case shows just one address.

Everything else seems to show the address to the jump table, but the 'printStuff' and '&printStuff' watch expressions show the actual address where the function code is located.

See also:
[jump stubs in PE files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957813/jump-stubs-in-pe-files)